# create a view which gets rank,username and count of user records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table below .I am unable to create view which displays count of records w.r.t user and username from another table and rank ,lets say for category '1'.How do I create a view ? I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
user varchar(255),
 category int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
username varchar(255),
 userid int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (user, category ) VALUES
('1', '1'),
('1', '2'),
('1', '3'),
('1', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('3', '1'),
('2', '1'),
('4', '1'),
('4', '1'),
('2', '1');


INSERT INTO tblB (userid, username ) VALUES
('1', 'A'),
('2', 'B'),
('3', 'C'),
('4', 'D'),
('5', 'E');
```

I tried but not working:

```
create view v as
SELECT
  tblB.username,
  groups.*,
  @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
FROM
  (select 
    user,
    category,
    count(*) as num
  from 
    tblA
  where 
    category=1 
  group by 
    user, 
    category
  order by 
    num desc,
    user) AS groups
  -- left join: in case if data integrity fails:
  left join
    tblB ON groups.user=tblB.userid
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) AS init
```

Result should be like :

```
  username   user      category     num   rank  
    B           2      1            6       1
    A           1      1            2       2
    D           4      1            2       3
    C           3      1            1       4
```

Comment: This is all SQL, are you sure you meant to tag this as "android"? We can't help you if you have nothing to show us.

Comment: What should the result actually look like?

Comment: @Strawberry hi strawberry I have updated the q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. Just needed to make minor changes. The following query will give you the desired results. In inner query got the first 4 columns and to get rank cross joined that to `(SELECT @curRank := 0) r` which is MySQL trick for getting rank. in the end just needed to order by Cnt to make it work.

```
SELECT username
    ,userid
    ,category
    ,Cnt
    ,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM (
            SELECT b.Username
                ,B.userid
                ,A.category
                ,count(*) Cnt
            FROM tblb B 
            JOIN tbla A
                ON B.UserID = A.User
            WHERE a.Category = 1
            GROUP BY b.username
        )a
,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r
Order by cnt desc
```

In order to put it into View you can use hack described by [@Gordon-Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280080/assiging-rank-in-mysql-and-view-creation)

End code will look something like this.

```
CREATE VIEW TestView1
AS
    SELECT b.Username
           ,B.userid
           ,A.category
           ,COUNT(*) Cnt
        FROM tblb B
        JOIN tbla A
            ON B.UserID = A.User
        WHERE a.Category = 1
        GROUP BY b.username
        ORDER BY cnt DESC;

CREATE VIEW TestView2
AS
    SELECT t1.*
           ,( SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
                FROM TestView1 AS t2
                WHERE t2.Cnt > t1.Cnt
                    OR (
                         t2.Cnt = t1.Cnt
                         AND t2.userid < t1.userid ) ) AS Rank
        FROM TestView1 AS t1
```

`TestView1` is used to get first 4 columns that you defined. `TestView2` you just select everything from first view and than add column that checks to see if value that you selecting is ether bigger or smaller than value in first instance of that view.

Comment: your answer is wrong http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac600/11   look at the cnt values correct answer is  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac600/2  but I cannot make that into view

Comment: @jason I forgot to include where clause to only limit to `category =1` and to change from `ASC` to `DESC`. Now it will produce correct result.

Comment: cool the query worked but I still cannot create view with it `create view test1 as
SELECT username
    ,userid
    ,category
    ,Cnt
    ,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM (
            SELECT b.Username
                ,B.userid
                ,A.category
                ,count(*) Cnt
            FROM tblb B 
            JOIN tbla A
                ON B.UserID = A.User
            WHERE a.Category = 1
            GROUP BY b.username
        )a
,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r
Order by cnt desc`     ............. how to create view please help.

Comment: update answer to include syntax on how to create a view. Here SQLFiddle with finished product http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85136f/1

Comment: awesome Please explain: `CREATE VIEW TestView1
AS SELECT b.Username
        ,B.userid
           ,A.category
           ,COUNT(*) Cnt
        FROM tblb B
        JOIN tbla A
            ON B.UserID = A.User
        WHERE a.Category = 1
        GROUP BY b.username
        ORDER BY cnt DESC;

CREATE VIEW TestView2
AS
    SELECT t1.*
           ,( SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
                FROM TestView1 AS t2
                WHERE t2.Cnt > t1.Cnt
                    OR (
                         t2.Cnt = t1.Cnt
                         AND t2.userid < t1.userid ) ) AS Rank
        FROM TestView1 AS t1`

Comment: especially query testview 2.Please explain both

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure SaUce's answer's fine - but there still seems to be too much query there!

```
SELECT username
     , user
     , category
     , COUNT(*) num
     , @i:=@i+1 rank 
  FROM tbla a 
  JOIN tblB b 
    ON b.userid = a.user
     , (SELECT @i:=0)var 
 WHERE category = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY user 
 ORDER 
    BY num DESC;
```

Comment: your answer is wrong http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac600/12   look at the rank values correct answer is  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac600/2  but I cannot make that into view,How do I do that.